# extjs 4 and translation

Tags: extjs, extjs4, translation

I'm coding with extjs 4. I want to provide two language buttons for the French language and English language. I have googled the problem, but I didn't find a solution. I hope I will find a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Sencha introduced the following approach:

Keep translatable-text in separate configs:

```js
Ext.define('MyForm',
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    // the next config is translatable
    submitBtnText: 'Submit',

    // ...
```

Create another js file which overrides locale configs and include it (js file) in html page:

```js
// MyForm-fr.js
Ext.define('MyFormFr', {
    override: 'MyForm',
    submitBtnText: 'soumettre'
});
```

Take a look at [Sencha's official example](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/locale/dutch-form.html).

Comment: how to make >// the next config is translatable

Comment: @Bouaziz, by including translation file as described in second part of my answer

Comment: in the js file I put the name of composants? For example in my form I have a label with a useraname: my_label. Than in my js file I put: my_label:'mon_label'. But nothing was translated.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your translations (for example as overrides) in different files and load them according to the language. You can see an example here:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/locale/multi-lang.html

Answer (score 0):

I have token a look at the  [Sencha's official example](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/locale/dutch-form.html), but now I want to add the translation to my application. In the example that I have followed the files.js and the file.html are in the same directory, but my application follows the MVC architecture, so it differs.
I have a js file that contains words to translate:

```
if (Ext.app.ContactForm) {
Ext.apply(Ext.app.ContactForm.prototype, {
    formTitle: 'Contact Informatie (Dutch)',
    firstName: 'Nom',
    lastName: 'Prénom'
});
```

}
And my application contains just one file.html, so I don't know where to put the file.js, in the same directory of the file.html or in the view folder! And how it can be readable bye all the application